# REST HTTP Status code if error Mongoose

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, http-status-codes

Which status code i have to use when an error could happen. When get all banks from the mongoose database. The user only does this client action.

Clients action

```
GET Url: /banks
```

Mongoose code

```
Banks
  .find()
  .exec(function(err, banks) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.status(200).jsonp(banks);
    }
  });
```

I think statuscode 500 instead of 400. Because the client url is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error codes `4xx` denote client errors like, for example, invalid requests. However, in this case the problem is with the DB which is on the server side. So you should use `5xx`. In your example, `500` is OK.

You can find a quick overview of the different codes here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation.

While it may seem that status codes `5xx` is the appropriate status code for such errors produced on the server, not all errors from Mongoose are caused by internal server errors as the code suggests.

If one would implement [validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) inside Mongoose schemas, validations errors would be thrown up the stack and would pass through the `Model.save()` callback as an error as well. Even without validation, some built-in Mongoose errors such as the [Cast Error](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#casterror_CastError) are usually triggered by erroneous input data (*ex. accidentally passing the value of `undefined` from a missing URL parameter as the query for the `_id` field of a model*).

If you are validating input data before they are saved through the Mongoose models, it's safe to assume that the only errors you would get from such callbacks are internal server errors, which would then be appropriate to have `5xx` status codes.